# Put the button on the bottom center of the screen with the RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, button, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView and Button. Button is coming under the recyclerView. I want to put the button to the bottom center of the screen in my screen. That should not change in any device. Because in some devices button get disappear.

My Xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#33DADADA"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_toolbar"></include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#4dabf5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Distribution  Channel  "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/selectDistribChannel"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Search Products"
        android:singleLine="true" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/selectedItemRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:background="#33DADADA"
        android:padding="5dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bAdd"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (replace by Relativelayout)-

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bAdd"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: yes, some what good. still not fit to the screen. more height taken from the button layout. so recyclerview get less height

Answer (score 1):

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/selectedItemRecyclerView"
    android:layout_above="@id/button"
    android:layout_weight=1
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:background="#33DADADA"
    android:padding="5dp">

  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="write your text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```